# Another way to get push device token ios?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, push, onesignal, devicetoken

I wonder, is there another way to get the push device token without the delegate method:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(nonnull NSData *)deviceToken
```

because I used OneSignal, and they don't need to conform that method to get the device token.

Comment: show some additional code

Answer (score 4):

You can get the **push token** for OneSignal SDK like this:

```
 OneSignal.promptForPushNotifications(userResponse: { accepted in
  print("User accepted notifications: \(accepted)")
            
  if let deviceState = OneSignal.getDeviceState() {
    let userId = deviceState.userId
    let pushToken = deviceState.pushToken
    let subscribed = deviceState.isSubscribed
    print("pushToken ====> \(pushToken)") //Here you can get the token
  }
 })
```

Keep coding........... :)

Answer (score 2):

`OneSignal` API states **[`IdsAvailable`](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-native-sdk#section--idsavailable-)** is the method you would use:

```
[OneSignal IdsAvailable:^(NSString* userId, NSString* pushToken) {
    NSLog(@"UserId:%@", userId);
    if (pushToken != nil)
        NSLog(@"pushToken:%@", pushToken);
}];
```

Is the method to get the token; mentioned [here](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-native-sdk).

Comment: where u called this

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik: I'm pretty sure it's called in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions` (see the page I linked).

Comment: see this `[OneSignal registerForPushNotifications];` you can get the documentation on https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-native-sdk#section--registerforpushnotifications-

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik: Yes, that's the same page I linked already; `registerForPushNotifications` does not return the `token`, it allows the `IdsAvailable` method to if it returns `true`.

Comment: I know the method `IdsAvailable`, I just wondering how OneSignal can get the device token without conform the method `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(nonnull NSData *)deviceToken`

Comment: @kent2508: Because you are going through their API, in which they are using the `APN` method on their server, which acts as a middleman. I would not doubt they use that exact method in their backend, then translate the token to their own which you then use.

Comment: @l'L'l  Can you explain more detail about that backend method?

Comment: Instead of you calling `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` in your app OneSignal handles that on their end; in other words they take care of the interaction with Apples Push Notifications for your app instead of you. You then interact with the OneSignal API to get the APN notifications they are handling. That's pretty much it right there — a notifications middleman.

Comment: @I'L'l: I knew! I used to NSNotificationCenter to handle some AppDelegate methods like: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification, UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, ... but I found no nofication keyword to handle push device token :(
Can you show me how?